# Try-Catch-Finally | Understanding of control while executing try-finally block contains return statement

Tags: java

Can anyone please explain me code attached.How the control will transfer from try to finally and how finally will work without return statement.

```
class TryCatchFinally{

    int ID = 0;

    public Integer test() {
        try {
            return this.ID;
        } finally {
            this.ID = 2;
        }
    }


  public static void main(String ...s) {
   TryCatchFinally obj = new TryCatchFinally();  //line 1
   System.out.println(obj.test()); //line 2
   //line 3
  }
}
```

Actual output is -
   0

While executing `test()` function, I have changed the value of ID in finally as 2. I know if I write the `obj.ID` at line no#3 in main method output will be 2 for line no#3. I would like to know here, I got result as 0 for line no#2. Why? When finally actually been called here?

Comment: Because the value you are returning is not the same as `ID` AFTER the `return` is called - This also has to do with how auto boxing works

Comment: I fixed your indentation and you've broken it again with your edit. Please be more careful next time. Proper indentation makes your code easier to read.

Comment: so does it means, after return finally  is getting called? Could you please explain this concept in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `finally` block does occur. From the [docs tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html):

> This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break.

However the result gets "returned" (The method isn't exited, but the return value is stored temporarily) before the `finally` block is reached, so at the time of the return statement, `ID` is still zero.

```
public Integer test() {
    try {
        return this.ID;   //Still 0 at time of return
    } finally {
        this.ID = 2;     //This still gets executed, but after the return value is stored
    }
}
```

If you print out the `ID` field after the method:

```
TryCatchFinally obj = new TryCatchFinally();  //line 1
System.out.println(obj.test());
System.out.println(obj.ID);
```

Then you get:

```
0
2
```

Comment: @Michael -  What if finally also contains a return statement?

Comment: @saurabhgupta Then the return value in the finally block is what gets returned from the method

Comment: @saurabhgupta 90% of the time that's not going to be what you want to do; it's pretty much an abuse of what the finally keyword was intended for, but GBlodgett is right: [runnable example](https://ideone.com/dQcIFp)